# How to reset OS X volume after sleep using launchd?

Tags: macos, applescript, launchd

I'm been trying to write a plist file on which when I return from sleep mode, I always want to make my Mac volume to the minimum amount. However, it looks like the following plist doesn't work, with an error: `1:1: syntax error: Expected string but found end of script. (-2741)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>my.plist</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
            <string>-e</string>
            <string>"</string>
            <string>set</string>
            <string>volume</string>
            <string>output</string>
            <string>volume</string>
            <string>0</string>
            <string>"</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Also, when the following is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>my.plist</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
            <string>-e</string>
            <string>"set volume output volume 0"</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The `osascript` command functions well if I execute it from within Terminal, so I think it's due to how I set my arguments list to the plist.

So is it feasible to take the string argument like `"~"` in launchd? Or is there some other things that I'm missing here?

I suspect that it might be better to write the `osascript` command in shell script, and load the shell script to enable the Mac's volume to minimize... but is it the correct approach?

I use OS X Mavericks 10.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second launchd job ticket format is almost correct. Only a set of quotes need removing.

### Quotes

The quotes are no longer needed in the second launchd job ticket, so change:

```
<string>"set volume output volume 0"</string>
```

…to…

```
<string>set volume output volume 0</string>
```

#### Grouping Arguments

In this case, the quotes grouped the set of arguments for `osascript` to see as one item. Thus `osascript` gets two arguments, the flag `-e` and the script. This meets the requirements from the [osascript manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html).

When called through **Terminal.app** and thus through the shell, the quotes are needed to perform the grouping. When `osascript` gets the arguments, the shell has removed the quotes.

Without quotes, spaces subdivide each item passed via the shell.

When called through a [launchd job ticket](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html), the grouping is intrinsic within the array passed as `ProgramArguments`. In your first ticket, the array contained nine items and in the second ticket, the array contained three.

### LaunchAgent

Be sure to add this launchd job as a `~/Library/LaunchAgents` as `osascript` requires an active user with a graphical session.

This approach approximates what I do with Power Manager in [How to Set the Volume When Logging In](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2012-04-26-how-to-set-the-volume-when-logging-in/).

Comment: Thanks. How can I tell which arguments can be specified in one line (like this case) and which cannot (hence lots of `<string></string>`)?

Comment: I have expanded the answer to discuss a little about quotes and grouping. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent follow-up. Then for example, if I want to execute `mysql -uroot -e "sql_statement"`, then the devision is `mysql`, `-u`, `root`, `-e`, and `sql_statement` (without quote), right?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct but I am not certain. It seems the shell may perform an extra step in this example and actively split the `-u` from `root`. This answer shreds more light on the subject, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178181/command-line-arguments-use-of-space-between-program-argument-and-the-argument

Answer (score 2):

The second plist should work if you remove the extra quotes, but it only runs the command at login and not after waking up from sleep.

You can use [sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de) to run a command after waking up from sleep. Run `sudo -v` and paste lines like this in a shell:

```
curl http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/sleepwatcher_2.2.tgz|tar -x
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share/man/man8
sudo cp sleepwatcher_2.2/sleepwatcher /usr/local/sbin
sudo cp sleepwatcher_2.2/sleepwatcher.8 /usr/local/share/man/man8
cp sleepwatcher_2.2/config/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility-localuser.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility-localuser.plist
echo $'#!/bin/sh\nosascript -e "set volume output volume 0"'>~/.sleep
chmod +x ~/.sleep
```